# How to access a particular attribute in a Collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I want to access the name attribute from the practice table but I am getting Collections. My code looks like.

```
$practice = Practice::withTrashed()->where('id',$appointment->practice_id)->get();

dd($practice);
```

and result looks like

```
Collection {#697
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => Practice {#698
      #dates: array:1 [
        0 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #fillable: array:2 [
        0 => "name"
        1 => "email"
      ]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 42
        "name" => "DJ and Charlie Eye Associates"
        "email" => "vendorsupport@ocuhub.com"
        "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2017-01-13 06:29:14"
        "liferay_id" => 57238
        "deleted_at" => "2017-01-13 06:29:14"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [
        "id" => 42
        "name" => "DJ and Charlie Eye Associates"
        "email" => "vendorsupport@ocuhub.com"
        "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2017-01-13 06:29:14"
        "liferay_id" => 57238
        "deleted_at" => "2017-01-13 06:29:14"
      ]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to do , so I can get the name "DJ and Charlie Eye Associates". I used withThrashed method because this entry is soft deleted in the practice table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get an object from a collection and then you can get any property of that object:

```
$practice->first()->name;
```

Or:

```
$practice[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Either use foreach loop

```
foreach($collection as $collect){
    dd($collect->name);
}
```

or you can just convert the collection into array

```
$array = $collection->toArray();
dd($array[0]->name);
```

or

```
$collection->first()->name;
```

Hope This Helps You.

Ask if any query

Answer (score 1):

You could simply get this by using this

```
dd($practice[0]->name);
```

Or if you know that your query will return only one object you could use `->first()` in place of `->get()` and then you could use.

```
dd($practice->name);
```

`->first()` gives first object

`->get()` gives array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
$practice = Practice::withTrashed()->where('id',$appointment->practice_id)->get()->get('name');

dd($practice);
```

Though this is incredibly ugly and you probably read up on Collections: your statement is doing exactly what Laravel says it does.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` if `id` is the primary key, you will get just the Practice back.

```
 $practice = Practice::withTrashed()->find($appointment->practice_id);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models